# JNI How to call java and call back native, And how to get JVM std io

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm dev in windows but not using windows lib.

The "initiative" mode JNI which run java first and using `Systen.load()` then call native method.
Or "passive" mode, The executable create JVM `JNI_CreateJavaVM` then call java method.

Now, I'm trying make a C++ program with JNI SDK, So that thing must be single executable, No dll for `System.load()`.

First write a hello world:

```java
public static native int nativeSum(int a, int b);

public static int sum(int a, int b) {
    return nativeSum(a, b);
}
```

and run `javah Driver` got this header define

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Driver_nativeSum (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint);
```

and run `javap -s Driver` make sure using right name

```
  public static native int nativeSum(int, int);
    descriptor: (II)I

  public static int sum(int, int);
    descriptor: (II)I
```

write the main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "jni.h"
#include "Driver.h"


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Driver_nativeSum(JNIEnv*, jclass, jint a, jint b) {
    std::cout << "Native invoked " << std::endl;
    return a + b;
}


int main() {
    
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = true;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    
    auto* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    
    std::string cmd = "-Djava.class.path=../class/out/production/class";
    
    options[0].optionString = const_cast<char*>(cmd.c_str());
    
    vm_args.options = options;
    
    JavaVM* jvm;
    JNIEnv* env;
    
    jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**) &env, &vm_args);

    delete[] options;


    // ==========================================================

    _jclass* jClass_Driver = env->FindClass("Driver");

    _jmethodID* jMethod_Driver_sum = env->GetStaticMethodID(
            jClass_Driver,
            "sum",
            "(II)I"
    );

    std::cout << "Test-sum method id = " << jMethod_Driver_sum << std::endl;

    long jResult_Driver_sum = env->CallStaticIntMethod(
            jClass_Driver,
            jMethod_Driver_sum,
            1, 1
    );

    std::cout << "Test-sum Method called res - "
              << jResult_Driver_sum
              << std::endl;


    // ==========================================================



    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();


    return 0;

}
```

Result:

```
VM created
Test-sum method id = 0x1ebf4888
Test-sum Method called res - 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Well, 1 + 1 = 0, That absolutely make none sense.

Then I try to using `System.out/err` and `try catch` find the issus but get same result, That *thing* even cannot catch by java exception or even C++ `try catch (...)`.

```java
public static int sum(int a, int b) {
    try {
        return nativeSum(a, b);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Then make sure not anyother mistake, I bypass native:

```
public static int sum(int a, int b) {
    return 1234;
}
```

Working pretty fine, I got the 1234 value in C++ console.

※ First Question:

How to get JVM stdio stream? `System.out/err.print` wont show in "initiative" console.
But DLL std print will print in java console when "passive" mode.

※ Second question:

What happen in the native call? I should not get 0 result, How to fix it?
How to achieve the goal?

BYW - make no sense but nice try : using `CallObjectMethod` will get same result, using `GetMethodID` will return ID 0 and a long stuck exit with 1073741819 (0xC0000005).

Update 1:

```cpp
jmethodID jMethod_Driver_nativeSum = env->GetStaticMethodID(
    jClass_Driver,
    "nativeSum",
    "(II)I"
);

std::cout << jMethod_Driver_nativeSum << std::endl;

jint jResult_Driver_nativeSum = env->CallStaticIntMethod(
    jClass_Driver,
    jMethod_Driver_sum,
    1, 1
);

std::cout << jResult_Driver_nativeSum << std::endl;
```

Got this output

```
method id = 0x1ec97350
method result = 0
```

Update 2:

To make sure not extern C or thar else I just write the function body in h

```cpp
#include <jni.h>

/*
 * Class:     Driver
 * Method:    nativeSum
 * Signature: (II)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Driver_nativeSum(JNIEnv* env, jclass cls, jint a, jint b) {
    std::cout << "Java_Driver_nativeSum invoked" << std::endl;
    return a + b;
}
```

And use tool to make sure the function name is correct

[image: Dependencies tool]

And use `env->ExceptionOccurred` to get Exception, And there is one:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Driver.nativeSum(II)I
```

And None of with or without `exter "C" {}` block is working, All failed as result 0 and  `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

So, I think even the native required function in the exe file, The jvm can't find it.

Now the situation is :

My C++ program is `main` the entry, And write java SDK for plugin developer.

In runtime, C++ create JVM, Load java class, Invoke java method when event, And plugin use native to "do something", So how to ?

And I also try

```java
public static int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

I got 2 , Which is working fine. Only problem is java call native.

Comment: Lots of weird things going on in this code. Why do you have a `Java_Driver_sum` when the only method you've declared as `native` on the Java side is called `nativeSum` (not `sum`)? Why are you using `_jobject*` et al instead of `jobject` et al? Why do you use `CallStaticObjectMethod` to call a method that returns a primitive `int`? And why do you then try to cast that result to a `jstring`?

Comment: Your JNI call to Java succeeds, but the Driver class does not call its native method correctly: `Java_Driver_sum` does not match the expected `Java_Driver_nativeSum`. You can try to check this with `env->GetStaticMethodID(
jClass_Driver,
"nativeSum",
"(II)I"
);`

Comment: @AlexCohn Sorry for I post old version code, But in local is matched, I edit it , and update1 , same result

Comment: If there is no copy/paste mistake again, the call is still to the non-native `jMethod_Driver_sum` method

Comment: @AlexCohn It's perfectly normal to call a non-`native` Java method from C++. The `native` methods would be used in the opposite case (calling C++ from Java). Although before the edits the code was all wrong.

Comment: I suggest you log the values of the arguments at every step of the way to see what they contain.

Comment: @Michael sure there is noting wrong in calling non-native java from C++, but the whole purpose of **[Update 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63464804/3)** was to prove that the *native* method can be loaded and works correctly.

Comment: Pretty sure that if you insert an `ExceptionOccured` or `ExceptionDescribe` after `CallStaticIntMethod` you will see a Throwable from `sum()` (catching Èxception`is not enough). Always check for errors when calling Java from native code.

Comment: Since this is C++, your `JNIEXPORT`ed functions should probably be in an `extern "C"` block in order for those functions to be exported with the correct name. This ought to have shown up as an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` when you run your program.

Comment: @Michael, it's probably declared as `extern "C"` in **Driver.h**.

Comment: @Michael I got the exception in update 2 , Do have a UnsatisfiedLinkError. So the question become : How to call back without `System.load` because C++ is entry, C++ is parent and  Jvm is child.

Comment: See also *[How to package statically loaded JNI libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220838/how-to-package-statically-loaded-jni-libraries)*

Comment: The image you attached in *Update 2* shows that the function is 'demumbled', which means that the C++ compiler did mangle its name. For JNI to find it, the function should be marked `extern "C"`.

Comment: See also *[Can't find JNI_OnLoad_libname in example program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34959562/192373)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access native methods, you still must call `System.LoadLibrary()`. The [spec](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/178#JNI-Specification-Changes) explains that your **Driver.java** should look contain:

```
public class Driver {
  static { System.loadLibrary("driver"); } // this name must be matched!
  public static native int nativeSum(int a, int b);

  public static int sum(int a, int b) {
    return nativeSum(a, b);
  }
}
```

and in your **main.cpp**,

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Driver_nativeSum(JNIEnv*, jclass, jint a, jint b) {
  std::cout << "Native invoked " << std::endl;
  return a + b;
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNI_OnLoad_driver // this suffix must match the name used in Java
                                           (JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
  std::cout << "Native loaded" << std::endl;
  return JNI_VERSION_1_8;
}
```

Make sure that the linker keeps both `Java_Driver_nativeSum` and `JNI_OnLoad_driver` exported in your binary.

As for your first question, there is no separate JVM stdio stream, Java reads from the same `fd=0` and writes to same `fd=1` as all others.

Comment: That solve the problem. Even `add_executable` only one EXE file outputed, Still need `System.load` in java. That totaly blow my mind which "System.load is talking about load a libray" and now, I'm loading an EXE file, WOW.

Comment: I'm glad it's over. There was this strange `env->GetStaticMethodID(
jClass_Driver,
"nativeSum",
"(II)I"
)` that returned a valid **jmethodID** in *Update 1* that distracted me; I thought, this was an indication that `loadLibrary()` succeeded.